# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER P88
AFTER INSERT ON reparation    
FOR EACH ROW   

DECLARE
vope number;    
BEGIN    
  SELECT observation_reparation into vope from repartion;    
  if(vope IS NULL)THEN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || reparation.observations_Reparation || ' MODIFY libelle_piece NVARCHAR2(50)';    
END IF;
END;
/
```

I get this:

> error:table or view does not exist.

Comment: i tihnk you have the schema name, table name and column name confused. The trigger is on REPARATION, you select column OBSERVATION_REPARATION and you truncate table OBSERVATIONS_REPARATION from schema REPARATION. What table  do you actual want to truncate and what schema is it in?

Comment: @davegreen100  I want to do if the observations_Réparation field is not specified, the trigger will automatically insert in its place libelle_piece

Comment: ok i get that, but what table do you want to modify? is it really reparation.observations_Reparation

Comment: @davegreen100 name table is reparation i want modify column observation_Reparation to libelle_piece using Execute Immediate

Comment: so you want to RENAME the column rather than MODIFY it

Comment: @davegreen100 of course !

Comment: @davegreen100  can u help me please ?

Comment: Your code shows both of these table names: `reparation` and `repartion`.  Do you actually have both or is that just misspelled?  Also, are you really trying to rename a column?  That makes no sense.  Could it be that you're trying to get the column value from libelle_piece and insert it into the observation_Reparation column if no value exists for observation_Reparation? (though those appear to be different data types).  Also, why is there no WHERE clause in your SELECT?

Comment: Can you back up and explain the problem you're trying to solve?  Why would you want to issue DDL from a trigger?  Technically, that's not going to work.  A DDL statement implicitly ends the transaction and a trigger is not allowed to end a transaction so a trigger isn't allowed to execute DDL.  Generally, a row-level trigger on a table isn't allowed to query from that table so your `SELECT` would probably generate a mutating table exception.  And doing DDL on the table you're inserting into seems fundamentally misguided.

Comment: Plus: Even if the `select` was allowed (e.g. assuming you really select from a different table) the select would fail if the table contained more than one row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER P88
AFTER INSERT ON reparation
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
vope number;

BEGIN

  SELECT observation_reparation into vope from repartion;

  if(vope IS NULL)THEN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE reparation RENAME COLUMN observations_Reparation TO libelle_piece';

  END IF;
END;
```

if you also need to change the declaration of the column you will need another ALTER statement

```
alter table reparation modify (libelle_piece NVARCHAR2(50))
```

Comment: like that  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'reparation modify (libelle_piece NVARCHAR2(50))' ? @davegreen100

Comment: execute immediate 'alter table reparation modify (libelle_piece NVARCHAR2(50))';

Comment: If you actually caused the trigger to execute, though, you'd get an error.  DDL implicitly commits but triggers aren't allowed to end the transaction.  So you can't do DDL in a trigger.